# Vsftpd dose not work

Tags: connection, error-handling, vsftpd, filezilla

I installed VSFTPD, I did the settings, but it doesn't work. When I try to connect with FilleZilla I recive this error: - Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server

I googled the error, and I did all the things that I found still I can't fix this error. 
Thanks.

my config right now:
http://textuploader.com/ddn65

ony my pc firewall is off
and in fille zilla  i did this settings: https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=7876

and when i did that in fille zilla i recive this 
Response: 200 OK /
Failed to create listen socket, aborting. /
Connection closed

i searched that on the net and i found out that is firewall but my firewall is off...

///SOLVED:

I uninstalled vsftpd and i follow this tutorial :
:
""  digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04   ""
and now i works fine, and in fille zilla i have to use port 22.

Comment: What are some things you tried ?

Comment: I tried to change VSFTPD config  settings

Comment: FIle zilla settings, turning of firewall

Comment: Please [edit] your question with *full* details of everything you tried and what happened, including the commands you ran and their output, if applicable, and also including links to the online resources you used.  Thanks!

Comment: done, i added my config and the link i use for the fille zilla settings